# Extend pc monitor on 2020 generation tablet, by cable

Tags: screen, tablet, android-pc

Do tablets released in 2020 have a technology that allows to use them directly (no sofware to install, only cable) as a PC secondary monitor?

I want to buy a tablet to use it as secondary screen for my pc by cable and I want to know which features/hardware must have to be use it as secondary PC monitor.

I am asking because I have been using [spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/) to connect my tablet to PC via Wi-Fi. It works fine but if the connection is not good or the tablet processor is not powerful enough, there is too much delay between PC and tablet monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tablets are not designed to show display signals for e.g. a PC. Usually a tablet don't has any hardware support for receiving display signals.

Hence everything has to be transmitted via IP for example as video stream. Video encoding and decoding comes at a price that the latency is much higher that a standard HDMI or DisplayPort connection which mostly transmit uncompressed data.

If you have problems with your Wifi connection you can try to use the USB connection via `ADB` to establish a IP connection between your PC and the tablet. In detail the following command allows you to connect a TCP port on-device with a TCP port on your PC:

```
adb forward tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

Therefore if you configure a remote screen software to use the port specified here as forwarded port (or change the port forwarding to match the used tcp port on the software) you can get a Wifi independent connection.